# JS unaskedly upgrades http-requests to https

Tags: javascript, https

So I've got following problem:

While my resources (including my JavaScript) are saved on a https-server, my web module is running on a http-server. Now when I want to request an image through the web module (because it's stored on an external server), I create an Image object like the following code:

```
var image = new Image();
image.onload = mycallback;
image.src = "http://www.example.com/myWebmodule&src=image.png"; // notice the absolute url
```

Now when I try it out in a random Browser, it repeatedly tries to get the respource from "http**s**://www.example.com/myWebmodule&src=image.png" although, as mentioned, the host domain also runs with http. Only the JavaScript resource is loaded from an https environment.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which browsers have you tried specifically? I have pasted your above code into the console on Chrome 53 and the connection is made to `http://www.example...` Do you get the same when entering it into the console?

Comment: I think it doesn't necessarily has to do with the code itself but with the fact that the JavaScript file is stored on a https server. Both Chrome and Firefox act in the described behaviour...